# Using Data Protection API as a key manager for JWT

Tags: c#, security, .net-core, jwt, dpapi

I'm using JWT as a container for access tokens, and want to add the rotation of the signing keys. I found that Data Protection API provides this functionality out-of-the-box.

While DP API is the interface to (symmetric) encrypt/decrypt the data, JWT should be signed, so they are incompatible originally.

Would it be secure to have such flow:

1. JWT `kid` to store the Key Id from DP API
2. DP API to auto-rotate keys based on the time policy
3. JWT to use a custom `IssuerSigningKeyResolver` to retrieve the raw key from DP API by `kid` value

That means that all existing/expired keys can be used to validate any token. To invalidate the token, the key can be revoked/deleted from DP API key ring.

A custom invalidation logic for distributed applications: reload the keyring on token validation error, so the instance can get the most recent key that was generated by another instance.

My concerns:

1. Microsoft [does not recommend](http://IssuerSigningKeyResolver) using IKeyManager directly

```
Developers should very rarely (if ever) need to use the key management APIs directly
```

But I'm not sure where it is related to the key access rather than rotation management
2. Exposing the key id within `kid` JWT header. I don't see a security issue here, but it does not mean there is no such
3. There is no a simple way to access the key buffer

Did anyone try to do something similar? Is there a simple strategy for the key rotation/management?